# Help understanding the "predictive process" latent Gaussian Process model

Tags: gaussian-process

In a paper introducing a general framework uniting several approximation methods for Gaussian Processes (GP) operating by imposing sparsity on the precision matrix [1]. The authors mention a particular latent process model which I am a bit fuzzy on.  The way that this sparsity is achieved is by strategically assuming conditional independence between points: $q_y(i)$ is the set of variables that $y_i$ "needs"

To summarize, there is an index set:

$S = {S_1, \ldots, S_l}$

The variables $\{ y_i = y(S_i) | i \in 1\ldots l\}$ are distributed joint Gaussian.

The authors later specify that the $\{y_i | i \in 1\ldots l\}$ can be regarded as latent variables in an underlying Gaussian Process, from which we obtain observations $\{z_j = y_j + \epsilon_j| j \in O \subseteq\ 1\ldots l\}$ where $\epsilon_j$ is Gaussian noise (i.e. the noise terms $\epsilon_i$ and $\epsilon_j$ are independent) on some subset $O$ of the index set.

I am confused about the purpose of distinguishing between $z_i$ and $y_i$ at the exact same location.  $y_j + \epsilon_j$ is again Gaussian, so why not simply lump $\epsilon$ into $y$ and say that we obtain observations directly from $\{y_j |  j \in O \subseteq\ 1\ldots l\}$?  The covariance function may need to be redefined to have a "nugget" component, if it doesn't already possess one, but is this all we need to drop $z$ and focus only on $y$?

They make the following statements elsewhere:

> It can be more accurate but also more computationally expensive to condition on $y_j$ rather than on $z_j$; we will explore this tradeoff in Section 5. We always pick $y_i$ as the conditioning vector for $z_i$, because $z_i$ was defined to be conditionally independent of all other vectors given $y_i$. For the same reason, there is nothing to be gained by conditioning $y_i$ on both $y_j$ and $z_j$, and so we always take $q_y(i) ∩ q_z(i) = ∅$.

This indicates that the distinction is important, and is not simply a notational convenience.  What is the purpose of including a set of latent $y_i$ behind the observed $z_i$?

[1] A general framework for Vecchia approximations of Gaussian processes, Katzfuss & Guinness